# UITableViewCell textlabel content not displaying anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I have a UITableView and I am loading data. The header title shows fine, but the `cell.textlabel.text`is not displaying anything. (Note color is not white when taping on it it also does not show) But I can get the value of `cell.textlabel.text` in an AlertView.

Any help??

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellT";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[theTArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:0];
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [[theTArray objectAtIndex:section]objectAtIndex:1];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cell.textLabel.text];
    NSString *title = [[theTArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:1];

    UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [tableView reloadData];


    [theAlert show];
}
```

Pics:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWn8Z.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a linebreak in every text in the array at the first character. So removed it and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your cell.textLabel has width and height.

Try to call 
`[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];` after setting the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[theTArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Something wrong with your index. Did you mean indexPath.row instead of zero index?
With current implementation all cells within section will have the same title.

Comment: Nope, I use an multidimensional array

Comment: Ok, log text before assigning to `cell.textLabel.text`. What will you get?

Comment: 2014-02-10 19:37:28:816 RGZH[63632:1803] -[TermineViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 88] TEXT: 
Maturitätsarbeit, Meldung ausstellungswürdiger Maturitätsarbeiten... (exactly what it should be)

Comment: Can u show how did u log it, maybe u should set the color before setting the text?

Comment: see my answer (Yea i know i am dumb)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you return proper `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.theTArray count];
}
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *messageAtIndexPath = [[theTArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Make sure your both delegate and datasource are both set.

Comment: Tried both, did not work either. Note: the section title shows up fine. So datasource should be alright??